# Manga with an overpowered MC with the ability to control demons and monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga

So, first off, the main character is super overpowered. He finds a dragon in a forest and then beats the dragon and makes it his familiar type thing. It turns out that he has the same power as the previous demon lord (if I remember correctly), the power to control demons / monsters and/or a type of necromancy. He establishes his own territory and the other territories are afraid that he will want to take all of their territory. During one part 3 S-rank adventurers come after him and he kills one and resurrects him, and this newly resurrected demon helps him with the political side of the territory when he goes over to a different nation to talk about peace. When he went to the other nation, he requested its ruler, who is a woman, to kill her daughter, but he just wanted to test her. In the end, the daughter actually goes with him to his demon territory.

Comment: Do you remember anything else? was the main character a human, slime, goblin? Were they transported from another world?

Comment: Human I believe. and I do not remember if they were transported or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is [Sekai de Tada Hitori no Mamonotsukai: Tenshoku shitara Maou ni Machigawaremashita](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120006/Sekai_de_Tada_Hitori_no_Mamonotsukai__Tenshoku_shitara_Maou_ni_Machigawaremashita).

The main character starts the manga as a Hero, but has decided that class is too annoying to have. He went on a search for a Job Tome to change his class. The manga starts with him finding the tome and changing his class to monster tamer.

Later he finds an elf village and saves it from some wolves. After talking with the elf guarding it, he goes to the dragon and they fight in a forest. After he beats the dragon and makes it his, the dragon mentions that 1000 years before another monster tamer had challenged him and lost. Once they get back to the village the elf mentions the village's founder had also been a monster tamer, the one that challenged the dragon previously. We also find out that she was considered the demon lord by the humans.

After a night's rest, 3 S-Rank adventurers end up attacking his servants. He end up fighting one of them, with his monsters fighting the others. He nearly kills one of them, and the others flee. Afterwards, the defeated adventurer turns into a demon, who is under the main character's control. The dragon then explains that monsters were created by the demon lord. The dragon likens the process to necromancy.

Comment: Dude amazing thank you so much for finding it. Yea that is 100% the correct manga